# Display hierarchy in a single column

Tags: mysql

Looking to return a hierarchy as a single column...

```
q1
 1=image1
 2=image2
q2
 1=brand a
 2=brand b
q3
 1=company a
 2=company b
```

Example data...

```
CREATE TABLE test_hierarchy (
 question VARCHAR(10),
 id TINYINT,
 id_value VARCHAR(25)) ENGINE=INNODB;

 INSERT INTO test_hierarchy VALUES ('q1',1,'image1');
 INSERT INTO test_hierarchy VALUES ('q1',2,'image2');
 INSERT INTO test_hierarchy VALUES ('q2',1,'brand a');
 INSERT INTO test_hierarchy VALUES ('q2',2,'brand b');
 INSERT INTO test_hierarchy VALUES ('q3',1,'company a');
 INSERT INTO test_hierarchy VALUES ('q3',2,'company b');

 SELECT * FROM test_hierarchy;
```

Is this possible? Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry    this is being requested by an end-user. I've tried some different combinations but can never get to the exact request.

Comment: You have an end user who sits at a MySQL terminal?